# rabbitMQ for Blackberry

Tags: java-me, rabbitmq

As your know, RabbitMQ is the good open source project for message send / receive.

Now we have a BlackBerry project need use  RabbitMQ.

But, when we download the latest RabbitMQ client zip and import our project, we found many errors.

Through research we found that these errors are due to Java jdk version. The Blackberry jdk base on the Java ME, in other words, the blackberry API just only supports Java ME sdk, but your RabbitMQ client code base on the Java SE sdk, so, some RabbitMQ use the API can’t be support by RIM, such as
HashMap. Cloneable interface, EvevntListener interface and so on.

I have tried to modify those errors, but found it is very difficult, because change this will make some 
more error in other classes.

Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ with a Java AMQP API might not be the best way to achieve what you want in a JavaME environment. Have you looked into using, for example, STOMP? There's a STOMP plugin for RabbitMQ and you could use a STOMP JavaME library to communicate with RabbitMQ instead?

Comment: thank you for your help. Can you give me some more detail for STOMP?

Comment: It's a somewhat generic answer, but there's information on the RabbitMQ STOMP adapter page which should get you moving I think? http://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html

Answer (score 1):

At RabbitMQ Java Client page http://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html we see the lates version available. 2.8.4 as of today. But they keep older versions available on the site http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/

Try with the oldest version of the library and see if it works with Java ME http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v1.4.0/

Comment: What about the number of errors? With version 1.4.0 there should be less things to adjust, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, use the version1.4 can reduce more errors.
This is my project svn address, if you can, can you help me review those errors for RabbitMQ?

http://192.168.40.2/svn/Code/RabbitMQ (this is latest version 2.8) 
http://192.168.40.2/svn/Code/RabbitMQ_14 (this is oldest version 1.4)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you for trusting the community with your svn address, but you should not do this. It is a security issue for you.